# Insert and push_back a pointer to a vector of unique pointers give different compilation behavior?

Tags: c++, vector, c++11, unique-ptr

I have code as following

```
vector<unique_ptr<int>> v;
v.insert(v.end(), new int(1)); // this is okay
v.push_back(new int(1)); // this is wrong, cannot convert int* to unique_ptr<int>&&
```

Why does the compilation (vc2010) show the differences? Thanks.

Comment: even insert is failing with [GCC](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1NQj0D$4) and [clang](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1NQj0D$4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in VS2010, `v.insert(v.end(), new int(1));` is optimized to call`std::vector::emplace_back` which construct object in place while std::vector::push_back will try to copy/convert `int*` to `std::unique_ptr<int>` then it failed. To make push smart pointers into STL container you can specify exact type:

```
v.insert(v.end(), unique_ptr<int>(new int(1))); 
v.push_back(unique_ptr<int>(new int(1)));
```

Or simply call

```
v.emplace_back(new int(1));
```

I've tested your code on VS2010 and VS2012, howerver VS2012 disallows `v.insert(v.end(), new int(1));`, but emplace_back works in both cases.

Comment: For the three options your provided, which one is faster? Or they are same? Thanks.

Comment: have a look at emplace_back: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: I don't think the emplace back method is safe. The new int(1) call can succeed then if the vector needs to grow that can fail which will throw an exception. I think the throw then happens after the new int(1) call but before the unique_ptr is created therefore causing a memory leak.